# C Array First Input "\0"

Tags: c, arrays, xcode

The arrays `[a]` and `[b]` are supposed to take in 4 numbers each on two separate lines, and output `?A?B`, as in the famous number guessing game. (For instance, `1234\n1347` should output `1A2B`.) However, I found out that the `1` at `a[0]` gets replaced by `\0` while the others are still fine. (Side-note: This happened on XCode, but not on Visual Studio.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[4], b[4];
    int i, j;
    int A = 0, B = 0;

    scanf("%s%s",a,b);

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        if(a[i] == b[i])
            A++;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            if(a[i] == b[j])
                B++;

    B = B-A;

    printf("%dA%dB\n",A,B);

    return 0;
}
```

Changing the arrays to size `[5]` solves the problem, but I want to understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Source of all problems: `scanf("%s%s",a,b);`

Comment: Could you please tell me more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are really called [***null terminated*** byte strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). That name gives a hint that there is a special terminator for the strings, which is the `'\0'` character.

A string of four characters needs space for *five* characters, with the fifth being the null terminator.

When you input four characters with your `scanf` call, the function will write the fifth (the terminator) *out of bounds*. And writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Is there any reason why it was moved to the front for array a?

Comment: @BrianHo *Undefined behavior* is by its very definition undefined. But it's likely that the array `b` is before `a` in memory, and the terminator for `b` is written in the first element of `a`. However, that memory layout should not be counted upon, it's a compiler-specific implementation detail and can change between platforms, compilers or even after updating the current compiler to a new version.